# embedded perl in c - is there a flag for a "runitme error" for scripts executed by perl_run()?

Tags: c, perl

If a "runtime error" happens in a script that is executed by perl_run() in an embedded perl instance on C (actually C++11), is there a more reasonable way other than to look for "Runtime error in..." at the stderr stream?

I'm using perl 5.26.1.

Thanks!

Comment: It _might_ help to include a [mcve].

Comment: Check the return value of `perl_run()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch exceptions thrown by code executed by `call_*`, so use the approach described in [Calling a Perl subroutine from your C program](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html#Calling-a-Perl-subroutine-from-your-C-program), and refer to [`G_EVAL`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html#G_EVAL) in [perlcall](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html). Use [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) from within the called code to get Perl to execute a file.

Comment: Good idea! But i couldn't get `do` to be invoked via call_pv or call_argv. They give "Undefind subroutine do called" on STDERR. But anyway, I could do the trick with perl_eval.

Comment: `do` is not a sub; it's an operator. It's actually `eval_sv` / `eval_pv` that you need if you want to use `do`.

Comment: That's what I meant. I used `eval_pv` ("wrongly" said perl_eval).